# Cloud foundry - How to retrieve version of artifact of every app running across Orgs?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, cloud-foundry

In PCF platform, We have multiple Orgs and multiple Spaces within each Org.

Each space has multiple apps deployed with manifest file mentioning the artifact version. For example: If you **push** an app(`some-api`) is deployed with below manifest file that has artifact version(`0.0.1`).

```
---
applications:
- name: some-api
  instances: 1
  memory: 1G
  buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
  path: target/artifact.jar
  routes:
  - route: some.router.com
  services:
  - abc
  - def
  env:
    ARTIFACT_VERSION: 0.0.1
```

---

Goal is to have a dashboard of *app to artifact version* across Orgs. App that is in `Running` state

---

1) As artifact version is stored as environment variable of an app, **amidst push** of an app, across Orgs/spaces, Is it possible to retrieve artifact version of each app?

2) If no, what is the better approach to store artifact version of every app running in PCF? in order to retrieve the artifact version of any app in `Running` state across Orgs/spaces

3) To show the list of app's artifact versions in browser dashboard. Does PCF platform provide any tool(like [firehouse](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/loggregator/architecture.html#firehose)) to provide a dashboard of metrics available in PCF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build custom app with requested functionality (dashboard with all running apps and ARTIFACT_VERSION value) which will use [Cloud Foundry API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org).

There is also CLI version `cf env` ([doc](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/env.html)) for quick checking in CLI.

**Update:**

Apparently, you want to use event stream and not regular pulling of the app env state. In that case use Firehouse and watch for `Staging Complete` events, which will trigger `getEnvValue(ARTIFACT_VERSION)` action for the app with that `Staging Complete` event.

Comment: Polling the version using `cf env` is different from getting notified by PCF, when artifactory version is changed for an app, after immediately pushing an app

Comment: @overexchange, sorry "to retrieve artifact version" is pulling for me. But it looks like you want to watch for env variable change - answer updated.

Comment: For JavaScript/TypeScript app subscribing to Firehouse event(`Staging Complete`)... Am planning to write a Frontend app(for dashboard) and push in PCF. Do we have any api? Am not sure.. if watching would require a backend layer and notify front end...

Comment: Sorry, but implementation is not in the scope of this question.